# Need help about this multiclient-server program (not working) link included

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient, tcp, tcplistener

Hello I am studying tcp/ip ser-client programming in VB and I would like to ask help about this tcp/ip multiclient-server program that i found online http://www.drawbycode.com/blog/?p=218 . It has all the explanation on how the code works which is great but when i run the progam and click connect nothing happens. Thanks for the creator by the way if your here lol

Comment: You'll need to include some code here showing where you're having an issue. Also show what you've tried so far and where you think it is failing.

Comment: There are no errors found when running however when i click listen and connect  there is no update to the listbox of connected clients Ive made sure to input the right ip and port too. Ive also tried just a basic tcp listener using a console and found that the client side is working as it should be , but if i click connect to the made server nothing happens. Do I post all the codes here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your client is connected to the server.
Have you integrated the right Ip?
Can you please post the Code example of the config for more Details.

Comment: Ive made sure to input the right ip and port and also clicked the listen button on the server side however there is no change and the app becomes unaccessible I cant alt tab to it. Do I post the whole code here?